# Strict Standards: Accessing static property JCache::$_handler as non static

Tags: php, joomla, static, strict

I am having an issue with my business website, and it keeps giving me the following errors on my website and login:

```
Strict Standards: Accessing static property JCache::$_handler as non static in /home/doveheal/public_html/libraries/joomla/cache/cache.php on line 422
```

Also on my website is this error:

```
Strict Standards: Only variables should be assigned by reference in /home/doveheal/public_html/plugins/content/jw_allvideos/jw_allvideos.php on line 42
```

I have seen many tutorials on how to fix it via changing the strict standard settings in XAMPP, but this does not apply to me as I do not use XAMPP. Truth be told, I did not create the website (someone else did and it was handed to me), and I am really struggling to figure out how to solve this problem.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: Check if you have access to php.ini via your cpanel. If so use Lodder's answer. If not you're probably best off contacting your webhost.

Answer (score 0):

You will on your localhost (Xampp) have access to the php.ini file. Open it and search for:

```
error_reporting =
```

There will be a value after the `=` which you need to change to:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT
```

Once changed, make sure you restart Apache.

This is however somethign you should flag to the developer of **jw_allvideos** so they can fix it.

Hope this helps